# Concerning Roots of the cubic equation $f(x)=x^3+x^2-5x-1$ and the Greatest Integer (or Floor) function

Tags: roots, ceiling-and-floor-functions, cubics

### The Question

I got into a rather tight corner with this question. It says:

> Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be the roots of $f(x)=0$, where $f(x)=x^3+x^2-5x-1$. Then, the value of $\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+\lfloor\beta\rfloor+\lfloor\gamma\rfloor$ (where $\lfloor.\rfloor$ stands for the [floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) or greatest integer function) is:
>
> 1. $+1$
> 2. $-2$
> 3. $+4$
> 4. $-3$

### What I've tried

If we take $f(x)=x^3+x^2-5x-1$ and compare it with the generalized form $$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ we see that: $a=1, b=1, c=-5$ and $d=-1$.

Now, the following formulas are known:

1. $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{-b}{a}=-1\tag{1}$$
2. $$\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=\frac{c}{a}=-5\tag{2}$$
3. $$\alpha\beta\gamma=\frac{-d}{a}=1\tag{3}$$

But I don't know what to do next. I tried putting in values of $x$ from $-2$ to $2$ to see it $f(x)$ equals $0$ for any particular value, but without any luck. I know that in $(1)$, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-1$. But that, apparently, seems useless as the answer is (surprisingly):

> Option 4., i.e. $-3$

How can I work my way out of this? There's no need for a full answer (unless you absolutely insist); I could do with a hint.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs should be helpful. Like $f(2)>0;f(1)<0$

Comment: @ambigram_maker you can't have just one complex root! In your case you have three real roots.

Comment: @Joelafrite $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-1$, so it is quite impossible for me to have *one* complex root. (Sorry! I evaluated the rule wrongly; now I have *one positive root and two negative roots*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Descartes' rule, we can solve it as follows :

$f(2)>0$ & $f(1)<0 $. Thus, $\lfloor{\alpha}\rfloor=1$

$f(-1)>0$ & $f(0)<0 $. Thus, $\lfloor{\beta}\rfloor=-1$

$f(-3)<0$ & $f(-2)>0 $. Thus, $\lfloor{\gamma}\rfloor=-3$

Thus, $\lfloor{\alpha}\rfloor + \lfloor{\beta}\rfloor + \lfloor{\gamma}\rfloor = -3$

Comment: I am quite unfamiliar with Descartes' Rule as we haven't learnt it yet. But nice answer anyway. :-)

Comment: You can read the wiki article posted by @lab-bhattacharjee in the comments to your question. It's not too difficult to understand.

Comment: Is it the the preferred method for application in a competitive exam (i.e. is it the *fastest* way to solve this type of problems)?

Answer (score 1):

This one will do even if you are unaware of the Descartes' rule:

Draw a rough graph of the function and observe that the graph cuts the x- axis thrice: between $1$ and $2$, between $-1$ and $0$ and once between $-3$ and $-2$. You can reach these conclusions by calculating the value of $f$ at these points.

Thus, we have roots between these points and by taking their greatest integer function values, the required answer is $-3-1+1=-3$

Comment: [I verified it](http://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-5x-1&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-5&x_max=5&y_min=-5&y_max=5&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=1&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=600&image_h=600). This really is a nice answer, but I don't know if I'll be able to apply it in a competitive exam. But thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: @ambigram_maker, It works in all competitive exams (including the JEE) and is really short if you practice it.

Comment: Really? Is there a way to quickly calculate (or guess) the roots of a cubic equation (or *any* equation, for that matter)?

Comment: @ambigram_maker, we are not calculating the roots, rather estimating two integer points between which the roots can lie. However, there is no quick way to calculate the roots of any cubic equation.