# Finding roots of cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma $ are the roots of the equation $2x^3-3x^2-12x+1=0$.Then find the value of [$\alpha$]+[$\beta$]+[$\gamma$],where [.] denotes greatest integer function.

My attempt:
I first tried hit and trial to guess the first root but no luck.Then I tried rational root method, but its roots are not rational (both roots could not satisfy the equation.)

I think its roots are irrational. Can someone help me finding its roots?

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302151/concerning-roots-of-the-cubic-equation-fx-x3x2-5x-1-and-the-greatest-inte

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Localise the roots between two consecutive integers and use the *Intermediate value theorem*.

Let $p(x)=2x^3-3x^2-12x+1$. As $p'(x)=6x^2-6x-12=6(x+1)(x-2)$, $p(x)$  has a local maximum at $x=-1$ and a local minimum at $x=2$:
$$p(-1)=8,\quad p(2)=-19.$$
Thus we know there are three real roots: $x1<-1$, $-1< x_2 <2$, $x_3>2$.  Now a table of the values of $p(x)$ at some integer points will do:
$$\begin{matrix}x&p(x)\\\hline-2&-3\\-1&8\\0&1\\1&-12\\2&-19\\3&-8\\4&33\end{matrix}$$
Hence $\lfloor x_1\rfloor=-2$, $\lfloor x_2\rfloor=0$, $\lfloor x_3\rfloor=3$, so that $\lfloor x_1\rfloor+\lfloor x_2\rfloor+\lfloor x_3\rfloor=1$.

Answer (score 5):

**Let** $$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2-12x+1$$

**Now,**

$f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<0 \implies 0< \alpha <1$

$f(-2)<0$ and $f(-1)>0 \implies -2< \beta <-1$

$f(3)<0$ and $f(4)>0 \implies 3< \gamma <4$

$\therefore \lfloor\alpha\rfloor + \lfloor\beta\rfloor + \lfloor\gamma\rfloor = 0+(-2)+3=1$

Comment: This is clean, but it may be illustrative to clarify how you got -2,-1,0,1,3,4--you certainly didn't pull them from thin air, and doing so should deepen OP's understanding of how to approach such problems.

Comment: The first strategy to try on problems like this is: look at easy small numbers.  It is trivial to check $-1,0,1$.  You immediately get a root between $0$ and $1$.  Since $f(-1)$ is positive like $f(0)$, try $f(-2)$.  That works.  Since $f(1)<0$ the final root must be above 1.  Try a few steps up to see Ishu has two simple typos in the next to last line, which do not prevent getting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2-12x+1$, we have a sign change between $-2$ and $-1$, between $0$ and $1$, between $3$ and $4$.